# Is there a good alternative to Zeromq for iOS?

Tags: ios, message-queue, zeromq

I'm working on a client-server application where the server will receive short messages from clients and push them to other clients over tcp--something like Twitter. I decided to use Zeromq on the server-side which works fine. However I can't make it work in iOS 8 xCode 6. I read that people have used it on iPhone. I found some tutorials on the Web about compiling the Zeromq library for iPhone/iOS but none of them worked for me. Does anyone know an updated tutorial on compiling Zeromq library using latest xCode or is there an alternative to Zeromq which I can use that works fine on iOS? I need something like Zeromq which will handle broken messages and disconnected sockets and stuff like that for me, because doing all those stuff myself will be a lot of work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean pubNub ??  it's by far the biggest messaging network.  one line of code...

Comment: No I mean a messaging queue like Zeromq

Comment: Hmm, sorry if I misunderstood you.  I use pubnub as a messaging queue for distributed apps that need messages.  Cheers.

Comment: **First a TECH.NOTE**: ZeroMQ is a great & very powerfull scale-able Broker-less Formal-Communication-Patterns framework, yet it is **NOT** a Message Queue. **Second a StackOverflow Note:** What have you tried so far, Zeus? Post more details, where and why your efforts failed and what remedies you have already tried. StackOverflow community is keen to share knowledge, but do not ask others to make your job start-to-end, ok?

Comment: I think the MQ in ZeroMQ stands for message queue. Anyways after some some changes to this github project  https://github.com/PLG/ZeroMQ-Framework  i finally make it work

Comment: And the Zero part means?